# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR.getDrawingList()Ljava/util/List

Tags: java, maven, openxml

I am trying to open a docx file through url.

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument(uriSource.openStream());
```

uriSource is a URL. For eg. http://project-pool/37/sample.docx of my local machine on another server.

When I try run it on server and call it through web service it gives me the following  error.

**SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/demo] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR.getDrawingList()Ljava/util/List;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTR.getDrawingList()Ljava/util/List;**

But when I try to run the same code as Java application and use the same url it works fine.

Also, I searched at various place it asked me to add a following  maven dependancy.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
```

I added this maven dependency along with other POI dependencies but it still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you rebuild after adding the paven dependency?

Comment: Yes, updated the Project, clean and build all done. But no luck.

Comment: Did you rebuild after adding the MAVEN dependency?